# Base Class with Ability to Serialize Derived Class

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance

I want to create a base class that contains a property that serializes the current instance of the class. That way I don't have to add the `Payload` property to every class that I want to serialize, and if I wanted to change the way I serialize, I wouldn't have to change it in ALL my classes.

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public string Payload => JsonSerializer.Serialize(this);
}


public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public string ClientId { get; set; }

    ...other properties left out
}
```

The problem is that `this` is always in the context of the `BaseClass`, so it knows nothing about the derived class. I've read where it's bad practice for the `BaseClass` to know anything about the derived class. So in this scenario, what are my options?

Comment: The object referenced by `this` is still a DerivedClass, and the serializer will be able to access all its properties through Reflection.

Comment: Another option if you don't wish to repeat is Extension Methods.  Do a search for c# extension methods should help you out.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Hmmm...With the code above, I just get an empty object. However, when I move the ```Payload``` property to the derived class, It works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work with the following code:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Payload => JsonSerializer.Serialize(this, this.GetType());
}
```

See the explanation [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31742).